# Reassigning one column according to another using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am interested in replacing the value of -11 in one column "contra_end" to the corresponding values contained in "current_age", another column. -11 is a variable indicating current activity, and I want to replace that value with the actual age of each individual stored in "current_age". Age has ~500,000 values and only ~4,000 values from the first column have the value -11. When I run the following code to assign my age column values to the -11 values in "contra_end" I get the following error. Can I make this work without creating a new age variable?

```
biobank[contra_end == -11, contra_end := biobank[,"current_age", with=FALSE]]

Error in `[.data.table`(biobank, contra_end == -11, `:=`(contra_end, biobank[,  : 
  Supplied 500000 items to be assigned to 4919 items of column 'contra_end'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Comment: i think Michael is trying to say `actualDT[contra_end==-11, contra_end := lookupTbl[.SD, on=.(individual_id), x.current_age]]`

Answer (score 0):

I used a short dataset which I made using this code

`biobank <- data.frame(contra_end = c(0,13,15,109,-11,23,45), 
                       current_age = c(34,35,36,46,43,56,23))`

which gives

`contra_end current_age
1          0          34
2         13          35
3         15          36
4        109          46
5        -11          43
6         23          56
7         45          23`

Using the `tidyverse::mutate`

`biobank_2 <- biobank %>% 
              mutate(contra_end = ifelse(contra_end == -11, current_age, contra_end))`

Or using `base`

`biobank$contra_end[biobank$contra_end==-11] <- biobank$current_age[biobank$contra_end==-11]`

Both options give:

`contra_end current_age
1          0          34
2         13          35
3         15          36
4        109          46
5         43          43
6         23          56
7         45          23`

EDIT: I didn't even notice that you were looking for a solution in `data.table` until after I posted. It doesn't sound like you have too many records for either of the solutions I posted to not be efficient enough, though.